# How can I correctly map one to one in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm making REST API using spring boot and hibernate. Basically, it is goal-tracking app, where we have goal, milestones to achieve it and fixed number of statuses of a milestone like "COMPLETED", "IN_PROCESS" , "AWAITING". For now, I have problems with joining status and milestone entities. How can I set status by writing status_id while testing?

Here is 
[ER-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHZxf.png)

Milestone Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "milestones")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Milestone implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Size(max = 300)
private String milestoneDescription;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 300)
private String measureDescription;


@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dueDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "goal_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Goal goal;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
private Status status;
```

// Constructors, getters, and setters are omitted for brevity

Status Model

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 60)
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "status")
private Milestone milestone;
```

Milestone Controller

```
@RestController
public class MilestoneController {

@Autowired
private MilestoneRepository milestoneRepository;

@Autowired
private GoalRepository goalRepository;

@Autowired
private StatusRepository statusRepository;


@GetMapping("/goals/{goalId}/milestones")
public Page<Milestone> getAllMilestonesByPostId(@PathVariable(value = "goalId") Long goalId,
                                              Pageable pageable) {
    return milestoneRepository.findByGoalId(goalId, pageable);
}

@PostMapping("/goals/{goalId}/milestones")
public Milestone createMilestone(@PathVariable (value = "goalId") Long goalId,
                             @Valid @RequestBody Milestone milestone) {
    return goalRepository.findById(goalId).map(goal -> {


//milestone.setStatus(statusRepository.findById(milestone.getStatus().getId()));
            milestone.setGoal(goal);
            return milestoneRepository.save(milestone);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Goal","id", goalId));
    }
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCwFR.png), postman test says that status is null, but it supposed to be status name

Comment: Put code in question

Comment: @Antoniossss done